# What is the best way to centralize header for test suite of REST api in SOAP UI?

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I want to achieve centralization for header. I made an test suite for one API but it has authorization key in it's header for user. If I want to test for another user, I have to change authorization header in all test cases. Is there any way to centralize header authorization in SOAP UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable on a Test Suite level, e.g. `myHeader` with value 123.

Then set the required HTTP header to `${#TestSuite#myHeader}`. During the test execution the `${#TestSuite#myHeader}` is replaced with actual value of the variable, e.g. 123.

For further study you can visit [Working with Properties](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html) from SoapUI documentation.